# JavaScript appendTo HTML <form> codes are not recognized on my View

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

```js
var counter = 1;
$(function () {
    $('#addDonation').click(function () {
        $('<div class="card border-apoio mb-3" id="cardDonation' + counter + '">' +
              '<div class= "card-body" >' +
                   '<div class="row">' +
                       '<div class="form-group col-3">' +
                           '<label asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].Type"><strong>Tipo:</strong></label>' +
                           '<select asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].Type" class="form-control">' +
                               '<option value="Alimento">Alimento</option>' +
                               '<option value="Brinquedo">Brinquedo</option>' +
                               '<option value="Roupa">Roupa</option>' +
                           '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div class="form-group col-5">' +
                            '<label asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].Name"><strong>Nome:</strong></label>' +
                            '<input asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].Name" placeholder="Nome ou descrição genérica" class="form-control" />' +
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div class="form-group col-1">' +
                            '<label asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].Quantity"><strong>Quantidade:</strong></label>' +
                            '<input asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].Quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />' +
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div class="form-group col-2">' +
                            '<label asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].UnitsMeasure"><strong>Unidade de Medida:</strong></label>' +
                            '<select asp-for="@Model[' + counter + '].UnitsMeasure" value="Unidades" class="form-control">' +
                                '<option value="Unidade(s)">Unidades</option>' +
                                '<option value="KG">Quilograma(s) (KG)</option>' +
                                '<option value="L">Litro(s) (L)</option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-1">' +
                            '<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="removeCard(' + counter + ');"><span class="bi bi-trash icon-size-2"></span></button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                   '</div>' +
               '</div >' +
        '</div >').appendTo('#cardDonations');
        counter++;
        return false;
    });
});
function removeCard(index) {
    if (counter > 1) {
        $('#cardDonation' + index).remove();
        counter--;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
@model List<Donation>;

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Doações</h1>
</div>

<form asp-action="Doacoes" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

    <div id="cardDonations">
        <div class="card border-apoio mb-3" id="cardDonation0">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-3">
                        <label asp-for="@Model[0].Type"><strong>Tipo:</strong></label>
                        <select asp-for="@Model[0].Type" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Alimento">Alimento</option>
                            <option value="Brinquedo">Brinquedo</option>
                            <option value="Roupa">Roupa</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-5">
                        <label asp-for="@Model[0].Name"><strong>Nome:</strong></label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model[0].Name" placeholder="Nome ou descrição genérica" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-1">
                        <label asp-for="@Model[0].Quantity"><strong>Quantidade:</strong></label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model[0].Quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-2">
                        <label asp-for="@Model[0].UnitsMeasure"><strong>Unidade de Medida:</strong></label>
                        <select asp-for="@Model[0].UnitsMeasure" value="Unidades" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Unidade(s)">Unidades</option>
                            <option value="KG">Quilograma(s) (KG)</option>
                            <option value="L">Litro(s) (L)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="removeCard(0);"><span class="bi bi-trash icon-size-2"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
        <button id="addDonation" type="button" class="btn btn-apoio-verde">
            <span class="bi bi-list-ol"></span>
            Adicionar Item
        </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-center mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-apoio-laranja">
            <span class="bi bi-plus"></span>
            Adicionar Lista
        </button>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

I use this code to add lines (in this case to add bootstrap cards) in order to create several objects with one submit button click. Basically instead of adding one object at a time, I want to add several objects at a time if needed, depending on how many cards I add on my code with the Javascript code.
Unfortunately, my program is only creatingthe first object, it never creates object @Model[1], @Model[2] and so on...

The view is not recognizing my counter from the Javascript html code that is added.

How should I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you don't understand how ASP.NET's Tag-Helpers and Model Binding work with `<form>` elements. **Note that `asp-for` is not a client-side attribute**. What matters most is the `name=""` attribute.

Comment: Could you please clarify.

Comment: Look at the **rendered HTML** that ASP.NET generates for you - and notice that `asp-for` is **not** rendered, nor are any references to `@Model`, but the JavaScript code you've posted shows you setting the `asp-for` attributes and hardcodes `@Model` as well. Do you see anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var counter = 1;
$(function () {
    $('#addDonation').click(function () {
        $('<div class="card border-apoio mb-3" id="cardDonation' + counter + '">' +
              '<div class= "card-body" >' +
                   '<div class="row">' +
                       '<div class="form-group col-3">' +
                           '<label for="[' + counter + '].Type"><strong>Tipo:</strong></label>' +
                           '<select name="[' + counter + '].Type" class="form-control">' +
                               '<option value="Alimento">Alimento</option>' +
                               '<option value="Brinquedo">Brinquedo</option>' +
                               '<option value="Roupa">Roupa</option>' +
                           '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div class="form-group col-5">' +
                            '<label for="[' + counter + '].Name"><strong>Nome:</strong></label>' +
                            '<input name="[' + counter + '].Name" placeholder="Nome ou descrição genérica" class="form-control" />' +
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div class="form-group col-1">' +
                            '<label for="[' + counter + '].Quantity"><strong>Quantidade:</strong></label>' +
                            '<input name="[' + counter + '].Quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />' +
                        '</div>' +

                        '<div class="form-group col-2">' +
                            '<label for="[' + counter + '].UnitsMeasure"><strong>Unidade de Medida:</strong></label>' +
                            '<select name="[' + counter + '].UnitsMeasure" value="Unidades" class="form-control">' +
                                '<option value="Unidade(s)">Unidades</option>' +
                                '<option value="KG">Quilograma(s) (KG)</option>' +
                                '<option value="L">Litro(s) (L)</option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-1">' +
                            '<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="removeCard(' + counter + ');"><span class="bi bi-trash icon-size-2"></span></button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                   '</div>' +
               '</div >' +
        '</div >').appendTo('#cardDonations');
        counter++;
        return false;
    });
});
function removeCard(index) {
    if (counter > 1) {
        $('#cardDonation' + index).remove();
        counter--;
    }
    return false;
}
```